# Как послать ифно с JSP на JS

Tags: javascript, java, java-ee, jsp

Всем снова привет. Нужна ваша помощь. Использую  `jsp` сервлет ,и в нем в `HTML` вставлен `Js google map Api` отображающий карту и т.д. Есть некая удаленная БД `Mysql` , где хранятся координаты, которые  я получаю в сервлете. А  теперь про то, что меня интересует... Могу-ли я полученные данные из `JSP java` передать в скрипт?

Если да, то какими путями? Был-бы рад хорошим урокам с отличными примерами.Так же если у кого-то найдется решение, я снова буду рад. И насколько тяжела задача??? Спасибо всем.

> П.Сы:Я не Русский за ошибки в тексте прошу прошения

Comment: Запишите координаты из базы в requestScope тем или иным образом: `request.setAttribute("x", mysql.getX()); request.setAttribute("y", mysql.getY());` Выводите <script> в JSP, используйте EL для подстановки нужных координат: `<script>initGoogleMap(${x}, ${y}, ${z}); var x = ${x};</script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вам необходимо из `Java` кода передать какие-либо данные в `JS` код.

Для данного подхода лучше всего подойдет `JSON`, как способ "взаимодействия". На стороне `JSP` вы формируете ваши данные как объект `JSON` ([ссылка](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson)).

Ну а чтобы отправить данные на `JS`, наверняка можно использовать `Ajax` запросы.

То есть цепочка вызовов такова :

1) `JS` делает `Ajax` запрос к `JSP` с ожиданием данных в виде `JSON`;

2) `JSP` принимает запрос и вытаскивает необходимые данные из `MySQL` ;

3) `JSP` формирует `JSON` объект ;

4) `JSP` посылает `JSON` на `JS`;

5) `JS` обрабатывает ответ (`.then(function(data){}`) и передает данные в нужное место;

Это как должно работать в теории. На практике можно столкнуться с проблемами. Например как сделать вызов JS запроса из JSP и обратно. И как синхронизировать данные процессы. Тут уже надо исходить из конкретного кода.

Comment: Понятно ,Человеческое спасибо!!!!Вы все пально понели)именно это и хочу сделать )

Answer (score 1):

Если данные уже известны в момент, когда страница отправляется сервером, то можно их в виде json'а поместить в скрытый input, а скриптом прочитать.

Comment: Спасибо щас буду пробавть все методы посмотрю что на практике полезнее окажется .Спасибо